# Subsets and Bijection

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}. Consider a subset of A that contains exactly two elements. For instance, {1, 2} is such a subset. Call such a subset a '2-subset' of A. Similarly, consider a subset of A that contains exactly three elements. For instance {1, 2, 3} is such a subset. Call such a subset a '3-subset' of A. Let B equal the set of all 2-subsets of A, , and let C equal the set of all 3-subsets of A. Explain why there is or is not a bijection between the sets B and C.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. I do understand that I need to have:
B {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {6,7}, {8,9}, but can I also have the same number like: {1,3}, {1,4}, etc? If so this will take a long time to list all possible outcomes for B and C.

Is there a faster way? If so how do I go about it and how do I find the bijection?

Comment: [Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Combinatorics_and_statistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count how many 2- and 3-subsets there are, if the number is different, there can't be a bijection.

There are $\binom{9}{2} = \frac{9 \cdot 8}{2!} = 36$ 2-subsets, while there are $\binom{9}{3} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{3!} = 84$ 3-subsets.

To explain the number of, e.g., 3-subsets, you can select the first element in 9 ways, the second in 8, and the third in 7; but this takes the order of the elements as relevant, you are overcounting by $3!$,